# Ajax call to a method that prints javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok,

I have a some javascript code in the database

Table: jsSnippets

Field: snippet

Type: Text

```
<SCRIPT SRC="https://svc.com/somestuff.js"></SCRIPT>
<script>
var fubar = 'stuf'
send_some_stuf_to_svc(fubar) // sends some data to a service :)
</script>
```

So i have N number of this JS snippets

will that code work if a server side method was called via Ajax call, for example:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: path + '/doTheJSStuff/',
            )};
```

where the doTheJSStuff is a method that echo/prints the JS code

Answer (score 3):

1. Your script must return javascript code (without html tags).
2. Call `eval(text)` after receiving text.

Answer (score 1):

That will work, so long as the contents of the `<script>` tag are being passed into javascript's eval() function. If you're using a framework such as jQuery, its built-in $.ajax() method eval's  tags automatically.